# Is my CPU 2nd or 3rd gen?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I bought a Toshiba Satellite C875 laptop that was advertised as a '3rd gen Intel i3 processor.

When I got the laptop the system info said:

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2348M CPU @ 2.30GHz, 2300 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

Did I get ripped off? Is this a 2nd gen Intel i3 processor?

Comment: Based on the product its a 2nd generation i3 processor.  You can verify what processor you have by using a program like CPU-Z since you don't seem to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: Yes. [List of 2nd Generation i3 Processors](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/59133). They may have assumed it was 3rd gen by the release date, since the 2348 was released in Q1 of this year, same time as many of the Gen3 processors.

Comment: Whats the difference between 2nd gen and 3rd gen? I feel like I was ripped off.

Comment: Bugger all. 22nm instead of 28nm. About 5% performance gain, most of which is obviated if the laptop has a dedicated graphics processor.